# Stringify a list to input it directly in hana_ml sql

Tags: python, sql, string, list

I have established a DB connection using hana_ml library which has a function to query from the DB as

```
with ConnectionContext('address', port, 'user', 'password') as cc:
    df = (cc.table('MY_TABLE', schema='MY_SCHEMA')
            .filter('COL3 > 5')
            .select('COL1', 'COL2'))
    pandas_df = df.collect()
```

I have a list of select columns in a list, and I would want to input the same. However, converting my list to a string representation also eliminates the quotes

```
a = ['COL1','COL2']

b = ','.join(a)
print(b)
--------
COL1,COL2
```

Is there a way I can stringify the list in the original format, where I get

```
cols = "'col1','col2'"
```

that I can input directly to my SQL Query

```
with ConnectionContext('address', port, 'user', 'password') as cc:
        df = (cc.table('MY_TABLE', schema='MY_SCHEMA')
                .filter('COL3 > 5')
                .select(cols))
        pandas_df = df.collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['COL1','COL2']

b = ','.join("'{0}'".format(x) for x in a)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
'COL1','COL2'
```